# Is a SanDisk Extreme Compact Flash card compatible with a Canon 5D Mark IV?

Tags: canon, memory-card

Is a SanDisk Extreme Compact Flash (CF) card (60 Mb/s) compatible with a Canon 5D Mark IV? If not, what is?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

> Is a sandisk extreme compact flash card (60mb/s) compatible with a canon 5d mark iv?

**Yes.**

> If not, what is?

Any CF or SD card will work with the camera, subject to the limitations listed on the [5D mark IV specifications](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/cameras/dslr/eos-5d-mark-iv):

> ```
> 1. CF card
>     Type I drive (Type II and Microdrive non-supported.)
>     UDMA Mode 7 supported.
>     CFast cards cannot be used.
> 2. SD, SDHC and SDXC memory cards
>     UHS-I supported.
>     MultiMediaCards (MMC) cannot be used (results in error).
>     UHS-II not supported. If a UHS-II card is used, it may be slower than a UHS-I (depends on the card specifications).
> ```

Type I CF cards are the ones that are commonly available. They're 3.3mm thick. Type II cards are easy to spot because they're thicker, at 5mm, and they're generally used for something other than flash storage (e.g. microdrives).

Comment: Also, specificially, SanDisk Extreme cards are UHS-I cards. From [SanDisk Extreme product page](https://www.sandisk.com/home/memory-cards/sd-cards/extreme-sd-uhs-i): "For SDHC (16-32GB) cards: Compatible with all SDHC/SDXC and SDHC-I/SDXC-I ( **UHS-I** ) enabled host devices. For SDXC (64-256GB) cards: Compatible with SDXC and SDXC-I ( **UHS-I** ) enabled host devices."

Comment: @scottbb That's a good point. The OP asked specifically about compact flash cards, but might not realize that "compact flash" or CF is a format distinct from SD. The 5DmkIV accepts both formats.

Comment: derp. I completely missed the CF part. I had SDHC/XC on my mind. =)